# How to do a function in python that loops through two or more data frames of different sizes and indexes in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am looking to create a function that loops through two existing dataframes I have based on some conditions and generates a value relating to those variables. Forgive the wording but for those familiar with excel the problem would be solved with index match and then normal equations within parentheses. The excel solution is simple but is static and does not cover each date or unit in my data as explained below.

I have created a smaller sample of my dataset which is fairly large and covers many date periods (one year), whereas in the sample I only show one date. There are also periods in the sample as column headers ranging 1-10, but in my dataset it runs from 1-48 for each day which I have shortened for the example here to make everything less clunky.

DF1:

| Efficiency Quintile | Date | MODELLED Rank | BM_Unit | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gas_1 | 08/01/2022 | 1 | FAWN-1 | 130.43 | 130.93 | 130.78 | 130.58 | 130.57 | 130.54 | 130.71 | 130.87 | 130.89 | 130.98 |
| Gas_1 | 08/01/2022 | 2 | GRAI-6 | 339.45 | 342.33 | 322.53 | 312.40 | 303.78 | 307.60 | 316.35 | 277.18 | 293.48 | 325.75 |
| Gas_1 | 08/01/2022 | 3 | EECL-1 | 363.31 | 386.71 | 364.46 | 363.31 | 363.31 | 363.38 | 361.87 | 305.06 | 286.99 | 282.74 |
| Gas_1 | 08/01/2022 | 4 | PEMB-21 | 334.40 | 419.50 | 436.70 | 441.90 | 440.50 | 415.80 | 327.90 | 323.70 | 322.70 | 331.10 |
| Gas_1 | 08/01/2022 | 5 | PEMB-51 | 370.65 | 370.45 | 359.90 | 326.25 | 326.20 | 322.65 | 324.60 | 274.25 | 319.55 | 288.80 |
| Gas_1 | 08/01/2022 | 6 | PEMB-41 | 337.00 | 423.40 | 423.10 | 427.50 | 427.00 | 419.00 | 361.00 | 318.80 | 263.20 | 226.70 |
| Gas_1 | 08/01/2022 | 7 | WBURB-1 | 240.41 | 293.17 | 252.27 | 256.51 | 261.65 | 253.44 | 247.14 | 217.08 | 223.11 | 199.27 |
| Gas_1 | 08/01/2022 | 8 | PEMB-31 | 297.73 | 360.27 | 355.40 | 357.07 | 358.67 | 353.07 | 300.93 | 284.73 | 268.73 | 255.20 |
| Gas_1 | 08/01/2022 | 9 | GRMO-1 | 106.62 | 106.11 | 105.96 | 106.00 | 106.00 | 105.98 | 105.99 | 105.90 | 105.47 | 105.31 |
| Gas_2 | 08/01/2022 | 10 | PEMB-11 | 432.80 | 430.40 | 430.70 | 431.90 | 432.10 | 429.30 | 430.00 | 408.30 | 320.90 | 346.50 |
| Gas_2 | 08/01/2022 | 11 | STAY-1 | 216.07 | 223.27 | 232.67 | 243.47 | 234.67 | 221.73 | 227.00 | 128.57 | 237.00 | 218.33 |
| Gas_2 | 08/01/2022 | 12 | GRAI-7 | 425.20 | 425.40 | 377.90 | 339.40 | 342.00 | 329.80 | 408.00 | 0.00 | 329.00 | 257.30 |
| Gas_2 | 08/01/2022 | 13 | DIDCB6 | 465.80 | 459.50 | 411.60 | 411.70 | 413.70 | 200.55 | 167.83 | 0.00 | 264.15 | 248.29 |
| Gas_2 | 08/01/2022 | 14 | SCCL-3 | 311.50 | 337.40 | 378.80 | 311.50 | 381.30 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |

DF2:

| Fuel | Efficiency Quantile | Quintile | Efficiency (%) | Emissions Factor (tCO2e/MWh) | Efficiency_adjusted_EF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gas | 1 | Gas_1 | 1 | 0.467 | 0.467 |
| Gas | 2 | Gas_2 | 1 | 0.467 | 0.467 |
| Gas | 3 | Gas_3 | 1 | 0.467 | 0.467 |
| Gas | 4 | Gas_4 | 1 | 0.467 | 0.467 |
| Gas | 5 | Gas_5 | 1 | 0.467 | 0.467 |
| Coal | 1 | Coal_1 | 1 | 1.046 | 1.046 |

DF3 (Desired):

| MODELLED Rank | BM_Unit | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FAWN-1 | 30.46 | 30.57 | 30.54 | 30.49 | 30.49 | 30.48 | 30.52 | 30.56 | 30.56 | 30.58 |
| 2 | GRAI-6 | 79.26 | 79.93 | 75.31 | 72.95 | 70.93 | 71.82 | 73.87 | 64.72 | 68.53 | 76.06 |
| 3 | EECL-1 | 84.83 | 90.30 | 85.10 | 84.83 | 84.83 | 84.85 | 84.50 | 71.23 | 67.01 | 66.02 |
| 4 | PEMB-21 | 78.08 | 97.95 | 101.97 | 103.18 | 102.86 | 97.09 | 76.56 | 75.58 | 75.35 | 77.31 |
| 5 | PEMB-51 | 86.55 | 86.50 | 84.04 | 76.18 | 76.17 | 75.34 | 75.79 | 64.04 | 74.61 | 67.43 |
| 6 | PEMB-41 | 78.69 | 98.86 | 98.79 | 99.82 | 99.70 | 97.84 | 84.29 | 74.44 | 61.46 | 52.93 |
| 7 | WBURB-1 | 56.13 | 68.45 | 58.90 | 59.89 | 61.10 | 59.18 | 57.71 | 50.69 | 52.10 | 46.53 |
| 8 | PEMB-31 | 69.52 | 84.12 | 82.99 | 83.38 | 83.75 | 82.44 | 70.27 | 66.49 | 62.75 | 59.59 |
| 9 | GRMO-1 | 24.90 | 24.78 | 24.74 | 24.75 | 24.75 | 24.75 | 24.75 | 24.73 | 24.63 | 24.59 |
| 10 | PEMB-11 | 101.06 | 100.50 | 100.57 | 100.85 | 100.90 | 100.24 | 100.41 | 95.34 | 74.93 | 80.91 |
| 11 | STAY-1 | 50.45 | 52.13 | 54.33 | 56.85 | 54.79 | 51.77 | 53.00 | 30.02 | 55.34 | 50.98 |
| 12 | GRAI-7 | 99.28 | 99.33 | 88.24 | 79.25 | 79.86 | 77.01 | 95.27 | 0.00 | 76.82 | 60.08 |
| 13 | DIDCB6 | 108.76 | 107.29 | 96.11 | 96.13 | 96.60 | 46.83 | 39.19 | 0.00 | 61.68 | 57.98 |
| 14 | SCCL-3 | 72.74 | 78.78 | 88.45 | 72.74 | 89.03 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |

I need the function to essentially help return an output similar to DF3 in the example that loops through DF1 and DF2 based on the following equation:

For each: date, BM_unit, period(1, 2, 3...) in DF1 multiply the values (e.g. 130.43) also in DF1 by the matching parameters in DF2: the number in the last column that matches the same column in DF1 (gas_1 = 0.47., etc).

The logic makes sense in excel though a simple excel function with index and match but based on the amount of conditions I know this needs to be a function that loops through all the dataset I am just a little confused on how to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In the output example you show, I don't get the logic you mentioned. The first value of first row in DF1 (e.g. 130.43): if you multiply it by gas_1 - Efficiency_adjusted_EF (0.467), it gives you 30.46 and not 60.91 (which is about twice as much). What logic is missing?

Comment: Apologies, you are correct there is another step which is to divide by 2. I just forgot to add that layer of the equation.

Comment: In the example, the index of the new dataframe seems to be able to be 'MODELLED Rank'. Is this correct? You say "For each: date, BM_unit, period(1, 2, 3...) in DF1," but it looks like you are iterating over 'MODELLED Rank' as a unique value in your DF1.

Comment: That’s just an example of how I have it matched in excel. I don’t necessarily need the output in a set data frame as I can call on the data though iloc based on date/unit id etc after the loop is done. Df 3 was just an example to help illustrate what I am after in a visual format. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is structured in 'wide' format which is a bit of an anti-pattern. (It's worth reading up on 'third normal form' - might seem in the weeds but it's one of those foundational concepts in relational/tabular data).

So step 1 should be getting it into a standard form (where each row is a unique 'value' with a unique 'index' - in this case the combination of the number identifying the 'column' - the sample? - and the BM_unit, I think. The `melt` method does this.

Then it's a simple merge to join the two (similar to a database join). Finally, if you REALLY have to, you can pivot it again... but really ask yourself if you have to.

```
variable_columns =  ["Efficiency Quintile", "Date", "MODELLED Rank", "BM_Unit"]
df_melted = pd.melt(df1, id_vars=variable_columns)
df_merged = df_melted.merge(df2, left_on="Efficiency Quintile", right_on="Quintile")
df_merged["calculated_column"] = df_merged["value"] * df_merged["Efficiency_adjusted_EF"] # I think this is the column you want?

# Are you REALLY sure you need to do this?
df_final = df_merged.pivot(columns=variable_columns], values=["calculated_column"])
```

I haven't tested that but hopefully that's close enough.

Comment: One thing I didn't explain in the post but the sample data set I have provided is of one single day. The reason I am building this model is to run it through each day in my dataset. For each day I have 48 periods (1-48) and there may be a variable number of BM_Units that will come up for each day. So that list of BM_Units will not be the same every day.

Comment: That is why I want to make a function for this so when I introduce this to a larger period I can loop through each day and then use .loc along with another function to run through each day to get the relevant information I need. It's the first step of defining the function I am stuck with atm.

Comment: I realised when posting the DFs I used the excel versions and not the ones I have in actual pandas dataframe hence the confusion on indexes. I have no posted a new post with the actual DFs as they are. Thank you for your answer but I think my question was incorrect.